# unable to delete a resource which belongs to another resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, path, resources

I have resources organized like this:

```
 resources :tickets do
    resources :comments
 end
```

When I try to use such link to delete a comment from a ticket (where they all are listed):

```
<table class="table">
        <% @ticket.comments.each do |c| %>
            </tr>
                <td><%= c.text %> | <%= link_to "Delete", ticket_comment_path(c), method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Are you sure?"} %></td>
            </tr>
        <% end %>
    </table>
```

I have an error:
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"comments", :id=>"5"} missing required keys: [:ticket_id]

as I suppose, for that ticket_comment_path(c) id should be an id of a comment and ticket_id should be filled.

But somehow my :id is a ticket ID and :ticket_id is empty...

Comment: Try `ticket_comment_path(@ticket, c)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using nested resource, the url will look like this

```
/tickets/:ticket_id/comments/:id
```

Therefore, to delete a comment you need to pass 2 parameters both `ticker_id` and `comment_id`. Your delete `link_to` should look like this

```
<%= link_to "Delete", ticket_comment_path(@ticket.id, c), method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Are you sure?"} %>
```

source: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources

Answer (score 1):

Try `ticket_comment_path(@ticket, c)` - nested resources need both IDs to be routes correctly. You can see the route by running `rake routes | grep comment` and you'll see something like `DELETE /tickets/:ticket_id/comments/:id`